# Where is the openjpa jar used as a -javaagent for websphere 8 applications located?

Tags: java, websphere, jpa-2.0, openjpa, load-time-weaving

Or do i have to provide my own? I want to provided load-time JPA entity enhancement following the documentation [here](https://openjpa.apache.org/builds/2.2.2/apache-openjpa/docs/ref_guide_pc_enhance.html):

```
java -javaagent:path/to/openjpa.jar com.xyz.Main
```

i want to find **path/to/**. Am I on the right track? Is this why [my entities are not enhancing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25416050/websphere-load-time-weaving-not-enhancing-jpa-entities)?

**UPDATE:**

I think I may have come across the file: `C:/<websphere-install>/plugins/com.ibm.ws.jpa.jar` however when i attempt to start up websphere with `-javaagent:"C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\plugins\com.ibm.ws.jpa.jar"` in the settings, the server fails to start up:

```
Error opening zip file or JAR manifest missing : "C:\Program
JVMJ9VM015W Initialization error for library j9jvmti26(-3): JVMJ9VM009E J9VMDllMain failed
```

It can't recognize the spaces for some reason. [I have read](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/rqmhelp/v1r0m0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.rational.test.qm.install.doc%2Ftopics%2Ft_instl_config_rqm_was.html) that

> These values *[jvm args]* must be encoded, which requires that any spaces in the file paths should be replaced with %20. For example, C:\Program Files would become C:\Program%20Files. If the JVM argument values are entered incorrectly, the WebSphere Application Server will not start.

however applying this change only gives me an error message with the %20s in the path:

```
Error opening zip file or JAR manifest missing : "C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/plugins/com.ibm.ws.jpa.jar"
JVMJ9VM015W Initialization error for library j9jvmti26(-3): JVMJ9VM009E J9VMDllMain failed
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use the -javaagent in WebSphere. WebSphere provides hooks to OpenJPA so that it can enhance without the agent.

The real problem you need to figure out is your Spring + WAS + OpenJPA question.